# How can I find a list of arguments for options.add_argument("xxxxx") using Selenium & Firefox?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I'm using Selenium & Firefox to scrape Youtube data and I implemented Firefox's "headless mode" with this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
```

I've seen other users use different arguments for this, eg:

```
firefoxOptions.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
```

But I can't find a list of these arguments anywhere on the net. Does anyone know where I can find such a list?

Project context: I'm trying to scrape data from a list of Youtube video links by opening each link with Selenium. The data I'm trying to scrape is independent of the media player. I don't want to load the media player because 1. the sound is annoying for the few seconds that the browser is open, and 2. I want the process to be as fast as possible and loading a bunch of videos is slow. If anyone knows a better way of accomplishing that without messing with Firefox options, please let me know.